# Android Menu coming from bottom like Google Drive

Tags: menu, panel, slidingdrawer

I have a floating action button and when the users taps on it I want a layout to be shown, animating from the bottom exactly like the Google Drive app (so not covering the whole screen).
I read someone suggest the open source Umano's AndroidSlidingUpPanel but that is more similar to the Google Play Music app and I don't want that as I don't need the panel to be draggable/slidable.

[image]

What component should I use?

Comment: I was about to ask same question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the Bottom sheet component. Check out its specs:
http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/bottom-sheets.html#bottom-sheets-specs

There are third libraries for the bottom sheet if you don't want to make it your self.